# pretty print a list using recurison returning single item in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I'm writing a code which returns each item in a list in "pretty" order. I'm trying to do this without using any built in modules or methods. THIS IS NOT A ASSIGNMENT, as I am just practicing and improving my coding techniques. The problem I'm having is that the function is returning just one single item and not every element in the list. I am separating each item in the list by the new line character. If the list has a nested list, I'm going to indent the items in the nested list by 2 spaces. Any help would be appreciated :)

```
def pretty_print(item_list, indentation = ""):

        if len(item_list) == 0:
            return " "

        for items in item_list:

            if isinstance(items, list):
                return pretty_print(items, indentation = "  ")

        return (items + '\n')
```

Comment: It only returns the first value cause of the return, which ends the method call. It also would work only for one level nested. I think it would be better to print directly and not return

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing that you need to return a string. This is the minimal change that you need to make in your program for it to work. Remember that your return values have to be consistent through the recursive calls.

```
def pretty_print(item_list, indentation = ""):

        temp = []
        for items in item_list:
            if isinstance(items, list):
                temp.append( pretty_print(items, indentation = indentation+"  "))
            else:
                temp.append( indentation + str(items) + '\n')

        return ( ''.join(temp ) )
```

EDIT:

In my program execution, the first element isn't indented. I changed the `indentation` string so it is easy to see in the following program:

```
def pretty_print(item_list, indentation = ""):

        temp = []

        for items in item_list:
            if isinstance(items, list):
                temp.append( pretty_print(items, indentation = indentation+"[----]"))
            else:
                temp.append( indentation + str(items) + '\n')

        return ( ''.join(temp ) )


print pretty_print( [1,2,3,[1,2,3], 1,[1,2,[1,2, ['a', 'this is outer'],3], 3], 2,3] )
```

And the answer is:

```
1
2
3
[----]1
[----]2
[----]3
1
[----]1
[----]2
[----][----]1
[----][----]2
[----][----][----]a
[----][----][----]this is outer
[----][----]3
[----]3
2
3
```

I am copying this directly from the iPython window .... There should not be any indentation in the first level.

Comment: The first element of a list is still indented, I am trying to indent only when a nested list is found, can we change the level of indentation in the recursive function to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a cleaner version in a more 'pythonistic' way:

```
INDENTATION = '  '

def pretty_print(item_list, depth=0):
    for items in item_list:
        if isinstance(items, list):
            pretty_print(items, depth + 1)
        else:
            print (INDENTATION * depth) + str(items)
```

Answer (score 0):

A for loop would help for starters.

```
def pretty_print(l, indentation=""):
    if isinstance(l,list):
        print (indentation+"[")
        for i in l:
            pretty_print(i, indentation=indentation+"  ")
        print (indentation+"]")
    else:
        print (indentation+repr(l))
```